# Entry widget: avoid more than one searchbar

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

In my code there are 2 buttons - when I click on the first, program writes into a window "home", the second writes into the window "search" and under "search" create searchbar. My problem is, when I click on the Search button twice (or more times) searchbar will created more times too. How can I fix it? (I always want there ONLY ONE searchbar).

```
from tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):     
        self.window = Tk()

        self.text=Label(self.window, text="Some text")
        self.text.pack()
        button_home = Button(self.window, text='Home',command= self.home)
        button_home.pack()
        button_search = Button(self.window, text='Search', command=self.search)
        button_search.pack()

    def home(self):
        self.text['text'] = 'home'

    def search(self):
        self.text["text"] = 'search'
        meno = StringVar()
        m = Entry(self.window, textvariable=meno).pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do here is add a variable that represents whether or not the application's entry has been created yet:

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):     
        self.window = Tk()

        self.text=Label(self.window, text="Some text")
        self.text.pack()
        button_home = Button(self.window, text='Home',command= self.home)
        button_home.pack()
        button_search = Button(self.window, text='Search', command=self.search)
        button_search.pack()

        self.has_entry = False

    def home(self):
        self.text['text'] = 'home'

    def search(self):
        self.text["text"] = 'search'
        if not self.has_entry:
            self.meno = StringVar() # NOTE - change meno to self.meno so you can  
                                    # access it later as an attribute
            m = Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.meno).pack()
            self.has_entry = True
```

To go even further, you could instead make the home and search buttons control whether or not the entry widget is actually *displayed*. You could do this by using the `.pack` and `.pack_forget` methods of the entry:

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):     
        self.window = Tk()

        self.text=Label(self.window, text="Some text")
        self.text.pack()
        button_home = Button(self.window, text='Home',command= self.home)
        button_home.pack()
        button_search = Button(self.window, text='Search', command=self.search)
        button_search.pack()

        self.meno = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.meno)

    def home(self):
        self.text['text'] = 'home'
        self.entry.pack_forget()

    def search(self):
        self.text["text"] = 'search'
        self.entry.pack()
```

Hope this helps!